# WHat is the difference between the filename_pb2_grpc.py and the filename_pb2.py files?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-python

From what I understand, the pb2.py file is code from the protoc file and the pb2_grpc.py file is code generated by protoc from the .proto file. But I don't understand what that means. I am very confused, can someone please explain this to me.

Thank you

I have tried to google the question, but I couldn't find anything that I could understand

Answer (score 0):

Both are generated by `protoc` or `python -m grpc_tools.protoc` (a Python module that wraps `protoc`).

A `pb2.py` file contains the core Protocol Buffer (message) definitions and is created as a result of the `--python_out` flag being specified.

A `pb2_grpc.py` file contains the service and rpc (method) definitions and is created as a result of the `--grpc_python_out` flag being specified.